# How to crop out gca and colorbar from gcf empty space in matlab?

Tags: matlab, crop, screen-orientation, figure

How can I remove the gray space to the right of the colorbar after it is introduced?

Before the colorbar is added to the gcf space, I use gca to hold an image and a logo because I need their dimensions and ratio aspect to not change once the color bar is added to the figure. When I add the colorbar, it is positioned to the right of the gca. The reason for the extra empty space when the colorbar is added is because I set the window screen size (gcf) to [16 9] which means that both gca and the colorbar will have a smaller width than the screen size of the figure (gcf). I have tried so many different ways to crop out the gca and colorbar from the gcg but every time I try the gca image gets warped.

I am using:

```
backMap=imread(...);
mapSize=size(backMap);
image(backMap);
screenSize=[16 9]
screen ='verti';
set(gcf,'units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1]);

switch screen
    case 'verti'
        set(gca,'Position',[0 0 (mapSize(2)/mapSize(1))*(screenSize(2)/screenSize(1)) 1]);
    case 'horiz'
        set(gca,'Position',[0 0 1 (mapSize(1)/mapSize(2))*(screenSize(1)/screenSize(2))]);
    otherwise
        error ('not well defined screen');
end
h1=colormap;
h2=colorbar;

set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);
h4=get(h_bar,'position');


pos=get(gca,'position');
figm=get(gcf,'position');

set(gcf, 'position', [pos(1) pos(2), 1-(pos(3)+h4(3)) pos(4)])
fig1 =getframe(gcf);
imwrite(fig1.cdata, [outputFileName2 'x3.tiff']);
```

Comment: Are you using script or GUIDE ? You can maybe have a look to set(YourHandle, 'Position', [0, 0.3, 1, 0.5]); to position your item.

Comment: Hello Alexandre, I just updated the code

Comment: This code doesn't work. What is h_bar ? I don't think it's h2, so... And you cannot really remove the gray space. You can move your bar or resize it to take all the space. Else I really don't know what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your case 'verti' for :

```
case 'verti'
    set(gca,'Position',[0.05 0 (mapSize(2)/mapSize(1))*(screenSize(2)/screenSize(1)) 1]);
```

and comment

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);
%h4=get(h_bar,'position');


%pos=get(gca,'position');
%figm=get(gcf,'position');

%set(gcf, 'position', [pos(1) pos(2), 1-(pos(3)+h4(3)) pos(4)])
fig1 =getframe(gcf);
imwrite(fig1.cdata, [outputFileName2 'x3.tiff']);
```

Your image look better, but I don't know what you need at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The size of the figure,gcf, is 1600px but I would like to save only the contents of gca and h_bar/h2 (colorbar) which is about 810px. I thought I could crop them out by using set(gcf, 'position', [pos(1) pos(2), 1-(pos(3)+h4(3)) pos(4)])
but that only warped the gca image.

Comment: Maybe you can try to store de fig1.cdata in a matrix and crop this matrix at 810px. like : MyImage = fig1.cdata; MyImage = MyImage(1:810,:,:); and after just call your imwrite.

Comment: That is sounds like a great idea, the only problem is I can't always predict that it will always be 810px. Is there a way to determine the pixel width of both gca an the colorbar based on the position or location of the colorbar?

Comment: Yes, like you did just do get(...,'position'); On the object you need and sum the width of the image + left position of the bar + width of the bar, so you have the full width no ?